# Does rolling back a changeset "reset" the changeset as unmerged in the original branch?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

If I merge branch A to B, then I rollback the changeset in B, then re-merge A to B, will the rolled back changeset appear in the merge set from A to B again (or is it considered already merged and dealt with from A to B)?